# When do you need a WebService or an Android Service?

Tags: android, web-services, service

I've been the last two weeks doing a lot of reading on Local and Remote Android Services, IPC, AIDL...and when I think I understood something I get all messed up again.

My intention is to send some data for another device to receive. For instance share an array of strings or any other object.

There is some basic concepts of arquitecture I still don't get: Should I have to implement a webservice that the app would have to listen to?? Otherwise how could the app in another device know there are "messages" waiting?

Could anyone draft a basic arquitecture for a typical task like this?

Messenger Service, Local Service, AIDL, Parcelable, Web Service??

Sorry for the ignorance. I'm really mixed up with very basic concepts.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Service

That is on Android a thing running in the background that handles tasks. Something like a Thread but more like an invisible Acitivity.

It can either be a local service (in the Process of the Activity that communicates with it) or a remote service. If it is a remote service than you need to serialize all communication between the processes. That mechanism is called IPC.

For IPC on Android you have AIDL to define a remote Interface of a Service (since you can't call methods in other processes) and you have the Parcellable stuff to serialize objects.

A Messanger Service is a type of Service that uses the Message class of android to transfer data between Processes.

All the stuff above is only for doing stuff inside your device. Not with other devices.

- Webservice

is something that involves a webserver and the Internets, it is not really Android specific. You better Wikipedia that :)

---

- How to send data from device A to device B:

there are several ways to do that, creating a Webservice that acts like a chatserver and allows to sends / poll messages for registered devices would be one way. Direct communication over TCP (in a local WiFi) another. Depends on what you need.

- App internal architecture.

A service that handles the network communication and lets your activities send / receive messages is probably a good Idea. But there is no universal schema to do exactly that either, it depends on what your app needs.

Comment: "All the stuff above is only for doing stuff inside your device. Not with other devices." Thx @zapl, that's what I needed to know. Any documentation on sending data from A to B? That would be out of the scope of Android SKD I guess...?

Comment: Maybe [that](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/903322/implementing-a-chat-server-as-a-webservice) or google "java socket programming" or "java webservices" or so :) There are endless possibilities to do that. Or [Android Cloud to Device Messaging](http://code.google.com/android/c2dm/) but that's more of a Webservice to device messaging thing.